# CodedUI Test Runtime to install in test server

Tags: automated-tests, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests, azure-pipelines

I'm using CodedUI Test for test automation, Currently I have installed VS 2015 Enterprise in the test server to support test execution. I'm not coding tests in test server.

Do I need to install visual studio enterprise in test server to execute CodedUI tests? Is there a run-time library to install in test server so that I can remove VS 2015 Enterprise from my test server?

Answer (score 0):

You can just install Test agent on the test server. With VNext build of VSTS, it can install and configure test agent on target server (test server), so you don’t need to install test agent manually.

1. Create a new build definition
2. Add Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment step/task and configure it
3. Add Run Functional Tests step/task and configure it.

More information about build definition, you can refer to: [Create and queue a build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/create)